# `which-key` displays "lambda" when key binding bound to lambda expression

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I'm using the [which key](https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key) plugin in my emacs setup and I notice that when I set a key binding in a keymap with a lambda expression, like this

```
(define-key my-yank-keymap "l"
  (lambda ()
    "Yank whole line"
    (interactive)
    (save-excursion
      (back-to-indentation)
      (set-mark-command nil)
      (move-end-of-line nil)
      (kill-ring-save 'doesnt-matter-because 'of-next-argument t))))
                                    
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c w") my-yank-keymap)
```

Activating `my-yank-keymap` with `C-c w` displays my key binding for the `l` key, but the label for it is simply `lambda`. Can `which-key` be configured to use the `DOCSTRING` of the function/lambda when there is no function name to display?

Comment: You can use `which-key-add-key-based-replacement` to change the description associated with a key combo (see the docs)

Comment: Since I don't have many lambda-based key bindings, this is an option, but I'd prefer to not to have to do this for every keybinding, but instead automate/configure this. Something like [here](https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key#key-and-description-replacement), but where you can give a function/lambda in the `cdr`, instead of a simple string. It looks like I have to just define a "proper" function with `defun` to get this working. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: You're welcome. You can probably also use 'general.el', it has support for which-key description when mapping, and can be used without 'evil':  https://github.com/noctuid/general.el#functions-to-help-with-key-definition (not sure if it's your use case, though)

Comment: Somewhat related: For an anonymous command, [Icicles key completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion), which is similar to `which-key` behavior, shows the key, together with the lambda-form itself (which includes its doc string, if any). E.g. `C-o  =  (lambda nil "Doc string." (interactive) (foobar 1))`

Comment: This doesn't do anything automatically, but the one-off customizations are [documented here](https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key#custom-string-replacement-options).